# swiftui matchedgeometryeffect is not smooth

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, matchedgeometryeffect

I have two views, one view has an `HStack` that displays a list of views, each containing an image and text. When one view is clicked, a detail view is displayed which will contain the image and text of the selected view.

The problem is the `matchedgeometryeffect` seems to fade in when transitioning between views. I tried different solution here on stackoverflow such as using `.zIndex()` and `.transition(.scale(scale: 1))` but nothing worked for me.

Here is the behavior I get in simulator: [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DZyKROpDktojcXYM6eX7T4w70MoB_O_I/view?usp=share_link)

Here is the code:

```
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        if let selectedCard = selectedCard {
            VStack {
                cardView(card: selectedCard)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation() {
                            self.selectedCard = nil
                        }
                    }
            }
        } else {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(topCardsAsTemplates) { topCardAsTemplate in
                        TopTemplatesCardView(card: topCardAsTemplate)
                            .padding()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation() {
                                    selectedCard = topCardAsTemplate
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@ViewBuilder
func TopTemplatesCardView(card: Card) -> some View {
    
    if card.uuid != selectedCard?.uuid {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                .resizable()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.uuid.uuidString + "image", in: namespace)
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 80)
            
            Text(card.backgroundType.rawValue)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.uuid.uuidString + "text", in: namespace, properties: .position)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
 //                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.uuid.uuidString + "text", in: namespace)
                                
        }
        .padding()
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.uuid.uuidString + "back", in: namespace)
                .frame(width: cardSize + 50, height: cardSize + 50)
                .background(.clear)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        )
        
    } else {
        
        Color.clear.frame(width: cardSize, height: cardSize)
    }
}

    @ViewBuilder
func cardView(card: Card) -> some View {
    
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: "person.circle")
            .resizable()
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.uuid.uuidString + "image", in: namespace)
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 120)
        
        Text(card.backgroundType.rawValue)
            // .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.uuid.uuidString + "text", in: namespace)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.uuid.uuidString + "text", in: namespace, properties: .position)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
    .padding()
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.uuid.uuidString + "back", in: namespace)
            .frame(width: cardSize + 200 , height: cardSize + 200)
            .background(.clear)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
    )
}
}
```

How can I make the transition smoother so that the fading-in and out are not shown? Any suggestions please?

**Edit:**
After a lot of trial and error, adding `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` to the `HStack` seems to solve the problem for me.
Here is how the `HStack` looks like now:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(topCardsAsTemplates) { topCardAsTemplate in
                    TopTemplatesCardView(card: topCardAsTemplate)
                        .padding()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("display card uuid: \(topCardAsTemplate.uuid.uuidString)")
                            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                selectedCard = topCardAsTemplate
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
```

Hope this helps other people.

Comment: I am having the same issue with removing the fade. I am trying to recreate the grid view from Safari Tabs and animate the tab to full screen. Your recommended fix of adding the frame maxes didn't work for me. Was there anything else you did to get it working?